# It is posible to put a component into a body component?

Tags: html, angular

I have this problem.
I have a component calls navbar and it is fix for all app.

```
<div class="wrapper" fixed>
    <nav id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{'active':!navbarOpen}">
        <div [ngClass]="{'sidebar-header':navbarOpen,'sidebar-header-active':!navbarOpen}" >
            <h3 align="left">CHROMAE PROJECT</h3>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="content" [ngClass]="{'active':!navbarOpen}">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">                        
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" type="button" (click)="myClickEvent()" >
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                            <span>MENÚ</span>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div align="right">
                    <button class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" align="right" type="button" (click)="logOut()" >
                        <span>LOGOUT</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in other component calls home i have this:

```
<app-navbar>
<div>
    <div *ngIf="getIsAdmin()">
        hola Admin
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="getIsModerator()">
        hola Admin
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="getIsUser()">
        hola Admin
    </div>
</div>
```

Can i put the "div" with ngIf like that?

```
<app-navbar>


navbar.div with id = content = {
    <div>
        <div *ngIf="getIsAdmin()">
            hola Admin
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="getIsModerator()">
            hola Admin
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="getIsUser()">
            hola Admin
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Because im trying too add inside navbar div class with id="content" that divs with *ngIf.
I dont know if i can explain my self :D

Comment: Why is the login ( getIsAdmin(),getIsModerator(),getIsUser() ) not defined inside the <app-navbar> logic .. ie navbar.component.ts and navbar.component.html

Comment: Because that functions only apply in home-component, not in another one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use something like `<ng-content>` and content projection. [Here is a useful article](https://alligator.io/angular/content-projection-angular/) explaining it a little.

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwax4t) demoing a very small `ng-content` example.

For quick reference, in your "parent" component (in your case your nav-bar) you will tell angular where you want nested content to go:

**nav-bar.component.html**

```html
<div class="wrapper" fixed>
  <!-- your nav-bar code -->

  <!-- nested content will go here -->
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Then when you use your nav-bar, you can "project" content into that `ng-content` tag:

**app.component.html** *(or any other component)*

```html
<nav-bar>
  Here is some content to project into the nav-bar's ng-content
</nav-bar>
```

See the stackblitz for the full code. There is also a way to have multiple `ng-content` tags using selectors. The article explains those if you need to have more projected slots.

It looks like you have some complex logic in your nav-bar so I didn't try to reproduce your code. The small demo should get you started in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the getIsAdmin in the own app-nav

Or you can use `<ng-content>` in your app-navbar

```
<div class="wrapper" fixed>
   ....
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

So, in your main.html you can do

```
<app-navbar>
   <div *ngIf="getIsAdmin()">
            hola Admin
   </div>
   ...
</app-navbar>
```

Comment: But if i do that i cant see the content "hola admin"